# How can I rotate an object and replace this object in SCNScene?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Currently, I make demo regarding ARKit. I am using two 3D objects `.dae` files. Also implementation of rotation of that object, but here I get issue how we do rotation only one time, because object continuously rotating?

How can I replace those object on screen?

I also mention below code.

```
func addAction(node:SCNNode) {
    let rotateOne = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat(Float.pi), 
                                       y: 0, 
                                       z: 0, 
                                duration: 5.0)
    node.runAction(rotateOne)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your function rotates an object only ones. The main question is, where you calling this method? Be sure, that you are not calling this inside *renderer(_:updateAtTime:)* or similar, otherwise your method will be called infinity. 
If you want to replace this object after animation you can use action with [closure](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnactionable/1524219-runaction). 
 
For example:

```
func addAction(node:SCNNode) {
    let rotateOne = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat(Float.pi), y: 0, z: 0, duration: 5.0)
    node.runAction(rotateOne) {
        node.removeFromParentNode()
        yourRootNode.addChildNode(newNode)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.